diffPool implementation in PyTorch for unsipervised clustering of homogeneous graph
I am trying to implement unsupervised multilayered clustering based on the difpool approach.
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.data import Data
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv, DenseGCNConv, dense_diff_pool
from torch_geometric.utils import to_dense_adj
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- Step 1: Generate a Random Graph Using NetworkX ---
num_nodes = 100  # Number of nodes in the graph
num_edges = 300  # Number of edges to ensure sufficient connectivity

# Create a random graph using NetworkX
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(num_nodes, num_edges)

# Extract edge index from NetworkX graph
edge_index = torch.tensor(list(G.edges)).t().contiguous()

# Generate random node features
node_features = torch.rand((num_nodes, 16))  # 16-dimensional node features

# Create a torch_geometric Data object
data_homogeneous = Data(x=node_features, edge_index=edge_index)

# --- Visualize the Graph Structure ---
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', node_size=500)
plt.title("Random Graph Structure")
plt.show()

# --- Step 2: Implement Multi-layer DiffPool ---
class MultiLayerDiffPool(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, num_pool_layers, initial_num_nodes):
        super(MultiLayerDiffPool, self).__init__()
        self.num_pool_layers = num_pool_layers
        self.projection = torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.gcn_layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        self.dense_gcn_layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        self.pool_assignments = torch.nn.ModuleList()

        # Initialize the number of clusters conservatively
        current_num_nodes = initial_num_nodes
        for i in range(num_pool_layers):
            # Reduce nodes gradually: Use a conservative reduction rate
            num_clusters = max(8, int(current_num_nodes * 0.8))
            # num_clusters = min(current_num_nodes, num_clusters)  # Ensure clusters do not exceed current nodes
            current_num_nodes = num_clusters

            self.gcn_layers.append(GCNConv(hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
            self.dense_gcn_layers.append(DenseGCNConv(hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
            self.pool_assignments.append(torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_clusters))

            # Print shapes for debugging
            print(f"Layer {i + 1} - x shape: {x.shape}, edge_index shape: {edge_index.shape}")

            S = F.softmax(pool_assign(x), dim=-1)
            layer_assignments.append(S.detach().cpu().numpy())


    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = F.relu(self.projection(x))
        batch = torch.zeros(x.size(0), dtype=torch.long, device=x.device)
        adj_dense = to_dense_adj(edge_index, max_num_nodes=x.size(0))[0]

        layer_assignments = []

        for i, (gcn, dense_gcn, pool_assign) in enumerate(
            zip(self.gcn_layers, self.dense_gcn_layers, self.pool_assignments)
        ):
            x = F.relu(gcn(x, edge_index))
            S = F.softmax(pool_assign(x), dim=-1)
            layer_assignments.append(S.detach().cpu().numpy())

            # Print shapes for debugging
            print(f"Layer {i + 1} - x shape: {x.shape}, S shape: {S.shape}")

            if S.size(1) > x.size(0):
                raise ValueError("Number of clusters in S cannot exceed the number of nodes.")

            # Perform pooling and update x and adj_dense
            x, adj_dense, _, _ = dense_diff_pool(x, adj_dense, S, batch)

        # Ensure that x is reduced appropriately
        x = x.mean(dim=1)
        return x, layer_assignments

# --- Revised Training Loop ---
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = MultiLayerDiffPool(
    input_dim=node_features.size(1), hidden_dim=32, num_pool_layers=3, initial_num_nodes=num_nodes
).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
data_homogeneous = data_homogeneous.to(device)

# Use the initial node features for unsupervised reconstruction
original_features = data_homogeneous.x.clone().to(device)

model.train()
for epoch in range(100):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    x, layer_assignments = model(data_homogeneous.x, data_homogeneous.edge_index)
    
    # Use the reconstructed x as the features for loss calculation
    reconstructed_features = x
    loss = F.mse_loss(reconstructed_features, original_features)
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Loss: {loss.item()}")

print("Training complete.")

# --- Step 4: Plot Layer Assignments ---
for layer_idx, S in enumerate(layer_assignments):
    print(f"Shape of S for layer {layer_idx + 1}: {S.shape}")

    if len(S.shape) == 3 and S.shape[0] == 1:
        S = S.squeeze(0)

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.imshow(S, cmap='viridis', aspect='auto')
    plt.colorbar(label='Assignment Probability')
    plt.title(f"Layer {layer_idx + 1} Node Assignments")
    plt.xlabel("Clusters")
    plt.ylabel("Nodes")
    plt.show()

# --- Step 5: Plot Graph Per Layer ---
for layer_idx, S in enumerate(layer_assignments):
    print(f"Shape of S for layer {layer_idx + 1}: {S.shape}")

    if len(S.shape) == 3 and S.shape[0] == 1:
        S = S.squeeze(0)

    cluster_assignments = S.argmax(axis=1)
    G_layer = nx.Graph()
    G_layer.add_edges_from(data_homogeneous.edge_index.t().tolist())

    colors = [cluster_assignments[node] for node in range(data_homogeneous.num_nodes)]

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    nx.draw(
        G_layer,
        node_color=colors,
        with_labels=True,
        cmap='viridis',
        node_size=300,
        edge_color='gray'
    )
    plt.title(f"Graph Visualization at Layer {layer_idx + 1}")
    plt.show()

Here is printed file from the above script:

Layer 1 - x shape: torch.Size([100, 32]), S shape: torch.Size([100,
70])

But it returns the following error.

{     "name": "RuntimeError",     "message": "index 87 is out of bounds for
dimension 0 with size 70",    "stack":
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In[88], line 94
92 for epoch in range(100):
93     optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 94     x, layer_assignments = model(data_homogeneous.x, data_homogeneous.edge_index)
96     # Use the reconstructed x as the features for loss calculation
97     reconstructed_features = x
...
File
d:\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\utils\scatter.py:75,
in scatter(src, index, dim, dim_size, reduce)
73 if reduce == 'sum' or reduce == 'add':
74     index = broadcast(index, src, dim)
---> 75     return src.new_zeros(size).scatter_add(dim, index, src)
77 if reduce == 'mean':
78     count = src.new_zeros(dim_size)
RuntimeError: index 87 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 70"
}

It seems that the number of clusters (pooled nodes) in the assignment matrix S exceed the number of available nodes at next layer. layer 1 - x shape: torch.Size([100, 32]), S shape: torch.Size([100, 20]) meand that we have 100 nodes with 32 features in x whereas the assignment matrix S is reducing these 100 nodes into 20 clusters.
I tried different settings, e.g., changing adjustment factor num_clusters = max(8, int(current_num_nodes * 0.8)) to different values, but it won't work. It seems that I am missing some basics but not sure how to find it.
Your insights highly recommended.
